# UNITY 2d - Can I refer to a parameter from animator in the player script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set the bool *Walking* parameter from the animator to false if the player doesn't move.

I already have a parameter called Speed, which works and it's only positive, so I want to say something like this:

```
if (speed == 0) {anim.SetBool("Walking", false); }  *//Where speed is a parameter in the animator*

else { anim.SetBool("Walking", true); }
```

Can I do something similar to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You indeed can. For this matter, you can use [Animator.GetFloat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetFloat.html) to get the value of the Speed parameter.

```
if (anim.GetFloat("Speed") == 0)
{
    anim.SetBool("Walking", false);
}
else
{
    anim.SetBool("Walking", true);
}
```